# Help needed to interpret a probability formula

Tags: probability, geometry

I am trying to implement [this paper](https://cis.temple.edu/%7Elatecki/Papers/IJPRAI08.pdf)  (*Skeleton-based shape classification using path similarity*) in Python but have difficulties understanding formulas **5** and **7** on page 7.

> $$p(sp'|c_i) = \sum_{sp \in G(c_i)} p(sp'|sp)p(sp|c_i) \tag 5$$ $$p(c_i|sp') = \frac{p(sp'|c_i)p(c_i)}{p(sp')} \tag 7$$

The goal is to find a shape (named "class") whose topology is the closest to a query shape.

[image]

*In this example, the probability that the query shape belongs to *class C* should be the highest*

More specifically I am trying to calculate the "posterior probability" that a query shape belongs to a given class (formula 7)

**What I understand**: This "posterior probability" is based on "path similarity", i.e how far/close the skeleton paths of the compared shapes ("query" and "class") are.

- a *skeleton path* (`sp`) is the route along the edges of the skeleton that starts at one vertex of the polygonal shape and ends at another one.
- the *distance* is the difference between the respective radii of the `m` equidistant maximum disks along 2 different skeleton paths

[image]

**What I DO NOT understand**: Path comparison.

**Question:**

Do I need to compare each path of the query shape against each path of a class shape (nested  `for` loop) ?
If not, what paths do I need to compare ?

Again, I believe understanding formula 7 is key to get this right

Here a fully annotated snippet in Python showcasing the example displayed on the first picture (query shape vs A/B/C classes):

https://trinket.io/python3/a0eb5843c0

Answer (score 1):

Skimming over the research paper and your code, the [prior probability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prior_probability) settings are

$\quad p(A) = p(B) = p(C) = \frac{1}{3}$

Also, these probabilities are initialized,

$\quad \text{If } sp \in A \text{ then } p(sp \mid A) = \frac{1}{132}$

$\quad \text{If } sp \in B \text{ then } p(sp \mid B) = \frac{1}{182}$

$\quad \text{If } sp \in C \text{ then } p(sp \mid C) = \frac{1}{130}$

If the input shape has skeleton paths $Q$,

$\quad \text{If } sp' \in Q \text{ then } p(sp') = \displaystyle p(sp'  \mid A) \,p(A) +p(sp'   \mid B ) \,p(B) + p(sp'  \mid C)\, p(C)$

(see formula $\text{(8)}$ in XIANG BAI's paper)

The first thing to do is see how the initial state is defined (all the input probabilities are initialized) and how you can 'turn the crank' on the formulas in hand and calculate

$\quad p(A|Q), p(B|Q) \text{ and } p(C|Q) \quad - \text{ check that they add up to }1$

For every $sp' \in Q$ you have to calculate $p(sp' \mid sp)$ for every $sp \in A \cup B \cup C$.

Comment: Thank you very much for taking the time to have a look at the paper. I have modified and annotated the Python code based on your explanation but notice that p(A|Q) + p(B|Q) + p(C|Q) doesn't equal 1. Could it be because of the "alpha value" from formula 4 ? Also the final posterior probabilities seem odds, they almost have the same value for each class (60.587, 60.485, 60.928) despite the topological difference.